# Visibility property not working if i set datacontext and vice versa

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datacontext

I want a user control to gets visible whenever menu is selected.

Whenever user clicks the vision menu, the AV_Credentials user control is shown. But i am unable to do datacontext for the new user control.

**Menu.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Connector.Views.Menu"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Connector.Views"
         xmlns:menuViewModel="clr-namespace:Connector.ViewModel.Menu"
         xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:Connector.ViewModel.AV_Credentials"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="350">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <menuViewModel:Menu_ViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <MenuItem Header="Credentials">
                <MenuItem Header="vision"  Command="{Binding Vision}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="NOP" Command="{Binding NOP}"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Sync"/>
        </Menu>
        <local:AV_Credentials Visibility="{Binding Path=AVCred}" DataContext="{Binding AV_Context}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Menu_ViewModel.cs**

```
class Menu_ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private AV_Credentials_ViewModel _av_Context;
    public AV_Credentials_ViewModel AV_Context
    {
        get
        {
            if(_av_Context == null)
            {
                _av_Context = new AV_Credentials_ViewModel();
            }
            return _av_Context;
        }
    }

    private Visibility _cred = Visibility.Hidden;
    public Visibility Cred
    {
        get
        {
            return _cred;
        }
        set
        {
            _cred = value; OnPropertyChanged("Cred");
        }
    }

    private ICommand mUpdater;
    public ICommand vision
    {
        get
        {
            if (mUpdater == null)
                mUpdater = new Updater(this);
            return mUpdater;
        }
        set
        {
            mUpdater = value;
        }
    }

    private class Updater : ICommand
    {
        private Menu_ViewModel obj;
        public Updater(Menu_ViewModel _obj)
        {
            obj = _obj;
        }
        #region ICommand Members

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            obj.ShowAVCred();
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public void ShowAVCred()
    {
        Cred = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

***What i am trying t achieve is -***

1. The menu will be blank.
2. When the user selects vision from the menu, the usercontrol will be shown in the menu.
3. There user will provide some data.

***Whats Wrong***

The visibility part is working fine, but the buttons and textboxes in the usercontrol is not working. If i assign datacontext, the button and textboxes are working, but the visibility is not working.

If required i can share the AV_Credential .xaml and .cs

Sorry for bad english

Comment: If you assgn a DataContext, also the Visibility binding will be resolved in this context. You want to add RelativeSource={RelativeSource ...} to access the Cred property in another DataContext

Comment: @KlausGütter sorry, i didnt understand.. could you explain a little ?

Comment: You are showing two "parts" of Menu_ViewModel.cs. Do they belong to the same class?

Comment: @DevDroneBhowmik: Add "AV_Context." to the binding paths in `AV_Credentials.xaml`, e.g. `<TextText Text="{Binding AV_Context.YourProperty}" />`.

Comment: @Clemens yes they belongs to the same class.

Comment: @Clemens I have updated it into a single.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i assign datacontext, the button and textboxes are working, but the visibility is not working.

Add "AV_Context." to the binding paths in `AV_Credentials.xaml`, e.g.:

```
<TextText Text="{Binding AV_Context.YourProperty}" />
```

This should work since the `DataContext` of the `AV_Credentials` control is a `Menu_ViewModel` and this type has a `AV_Context` property.

You should not explicitly set the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` because then the binding to the `Menu_ViewModel`'s `Cred` property will fail as you have already discovered.

The other option would be to specify an explicit source for the `Visibility` binding:

```
<local:AV_Credentials Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.Cred, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
                      DataContext="{Binding AV_Context}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks .The visibility binding worked. Can you explain a little why this worked ?

Comment: @DevDroneBhowmik: If you don't set the source of the binding, it looks for the property (`Cred` in this case) in the `DataContext`, which in this case is a `AV_Context` and this class has no `Cred` property.